Dynamic searchbox in C# windows form app with dropbox
I want to create a form with a dynamic search box in it for users to find what the want.
I have a table in may database with more than 1000 rows. I want to make my dropbox a dynamic search box which show the suggestions based on users text entered and the when the user find what he want, show the information of that row in database in the textbox which are already exits in the form.
I read other post like this question but I can't find what I need.
This is the code which I wrote myself but did not worked!!
private void comboBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchTerm = comboBoxSearch.Text.Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        var suggestions = GetSearchSuggestions(searchTerm);
        comboBoxSearch.Items.Clear();
        comboBoxSearch.Items.AddRange(suggestions.ToArray()); // Add suggestions to the combo box
    }
    else
    {
        comboBoxSearch.Items.Clear(); // Clear suggestions if no text is entered
    }
}

private List<string> GetSearchSuggestions(string term)
{
    List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();

    // Get data from the database (SQL query)
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Material WHERE MaterialName LIKE @SearchTerm"; // Adjust query
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", "%" + term + "%");
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                suggestions.Add(reader["MaterialName"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return suggestions;
}


You should include info about which UI framework you are using. Doing this in a "fat client" (WinForms, WPF, MAUI) is very different from doing it in a web client app (and web clients come in different flavors as well). Also "but did not worked!!" is not a problem description. You need to tell us what you expected, what you got, and how it "did not work"

I want to implement it in Windows Form application. The code which I wrote did not show any thing to me.
